# How to load not the entire page with regions (150), but only those regions that are in the current tab that is open in the page ? in apex oracle

Tags: oracle-apex

I want to post about 150 different regions on the page. But this page is loaded for 10 seconds, I divided them into tabs by 10 regions in the tab, but it did not help, the page loads for a very long time, can I make it so that it would not load the entire page, but only those regions that are in the current tab ?? Thanks for the help)
Each region has an Interactive Report type!
My qwery in regions(The only difference is the "where" parameter for each region)
In this code, I use color gradation to highlight each temperature with its own color

```html
  select 
        v.NAME_LVL,
        max(h.temp) as max_temp_lvl1,   
        min(h.temp) as min_temp_lvl1,
         CASE WHEN max(h.temp) <= 5 THEN 'data-style="background-color:rgb(0,0,255)"' 
            WHEN max(h.temp) >= 5  and max(h.temp) <= 6.2 THEN 'data-style="background-color:rgb(0,143,255)"' 
            WHEN max(h.temp) >= 6.2 and max(h.temp) <= 7.1 THEN 'data-style="background-color:rgb(0,39,255)"'
            WHEN max(h.temp) >= 7.1 and max(h.temp) <= 8 THEN 'data-style="background-color:rgb(0,71,255)"'
            WHEN max(h.temp) >= 8 and max(h.temp) <= 9.2 THEN 'data-style="background-color:rgb(0,102,255)"' 
            WHEN max(h.temp) >= 9.2 and max(h.temp) <= 10.1 THEN 'data-style="background-color:rgb(0,142,255)"'             
            WHEN max(h.temp) >= 10.1 and max(h.temp) <= 11.3 THEN 'data-style="background-color:rgb(0,174,255)"'             
            WHEN max(h.temp) >= 11.3 and max(h.temp) <= 12.2 THEN 'data-style="background-color:rgb(0,218,255)"'              
            WHEN max(h.temp) >= 12.2 and max(h.temp) <= 13.1 THEN 'data-style="background-color:rgb(0,244,255)"'               
            WHEN max(h.temp) >= 13.1 and max(h.temp) <= 14.0 THEN 'data-style="background-color:rgb(0,255,237)"'                  
            WHEN max(h.temp) >= 14.0 and max(h.temp) <= 15.2 THEN 'data-style="background-color:rgb(0,255,206)"'               
            WHEN max(h.temp) >= 15.2 and max(h.temp) <= 16.1 THEN 'data-style="background-color:rgb(0,255,167)"'               
            WHEN max(h.temp) >= 16.1 and max(h.temp) <= 17.0 THEN 'data-style="background-color:rgb(0,255,135)"'                 
            WHEN max(h.temp) >= 17.0 and max(h.temp) <= 18.2 THEN 'data-style="background-color:rgb(0,255,102)"'         
            WHEN max(h.temp) >= 18.2 and max(h.temp) <= 19.1 THEN 'data-style="background-color:rgb(0,255,64)"'               
            WHEN max(h.temp) >= 19.1 and max(h.temp) <= 20 THEN 'data-style="background-color:rgb(0,255,32)"'            
            WHEN max(h.temp) >= 20 and max(h.temp) <= 21.2 THEN 'data-style="background-color:rgb(0,255,0)"'              
            WHEN max(h.temp) >= 21.2 and max(h.temp) <= 22.1 THEN 'data-style="background-color:rgb(39,255,0)"'             
            WHEN max(h.temp) >= 22.1 and max(h.temp) <= 23 THEN 'data-style="background-color:rgb(71,255,0)"'                
            WHEN max(h.temp) >= 23 and max(h.temp) <= 24.2 THEN 'data-style="background-color:rgb(102,255,0)"'                
            WHEN max(h.temp) >= 24.2 and max(h.temp) <= 25.1 THEN 'data-style="background-color:rgb(142,255,0)"'               
            WHEN max(h.temp) >= 25.1 and max(h.temp) <= 26 THEN 'data-style="background-color:rgb(174,255,0)"'             
            WHEN max(h.temp) >= 26 and max(h.temp) <= 27.2 THEN 'data-style="background-color:rgb(206,255,0)"'               
            WHEN max(h.temp) >= 27.2 and max(h.temp) <= 28.1 THEN 'data-style="background-color:rgb(244,255,0)"'              
            WHEN max(h.temp) >= 28.1 and max(h.temp) <= 29 THEN 'data-style="background-color:rgb(255,237,0)"'            
            WHEN max(h.temp) >= 29 and max(h.temp) <= 30.2 THEN 'data-style="background-color:rgb(255,206,0)"'  
            WHEN max(h.temp) >= 30.2 and max(h.temp) <= 31.1 THEN 'data-style="background-color:rgb(255,167,0)"'               
            WHEN max(h.temp) >= 31.1 and max(h.temp) <= 32 THEN 'data-style="background-color:rgb(255,135,0)"'                
            WHEN max(h.temp) >= 32 and max(h.temp) <= 33.2 THEN 'data-style="background-color:rgb(255,102,0)"'               
            WHEN max(h.temp) >= 33.2 and max(h.temp) <= 34.1 THEN 'data-style="background-color:rgb(255,64,0)"' 
            WHEN max(h.temp) >= 34.1 and max(h.temp) <= 35 THEN 'data-style="background-color:rgb(255,32,0)"'            
            WHEN max(h.temp) >= 35  THEN 'data-style="background-color:rgb(255,0,0)"'                 
            ELSE NULL
           END css_style_max,
 CASE WHEN min(h.temp) <= 5 THEN 'data-style="background-color:rgb(0,0,255)"' 
            WHEN min(h.temp) >= 5  and min(h.temp) <= 6.2 THEN 'data-style="background-color:rgb(0,143,255)"' 
            WHEN min(h.temp) >= 6.2 and min(h.temp) <= 7.1 THEN 'data-style="background-color:rgb(0,39,255)"'
            WHEN min(h.temp) >= 7.1 and min(h.temp) <= 8 THEN 'data-style="background-color:rgb(0,71,255)"'
            WHEN min(h.temp) >= 8 and min(h.temp) <= 9.2 THEN 'data-style="background-color:rgb(0,102,255)"' 
            WHEN min(h.temp) >= 9.2 and min(h.temp) <= 10.1 THEN 'data-style="background-color:rgb(0,142,255)"'             
            WHEN min(h.temp) >= 10.1 and min(h.temp) <= 11.3 THEN 'data-style="background-color:rgb(0,174,255)"'             
            WHEN min(h.temp) >= 11.3 and min(h.temp) <= 12.2 THEN 'data-style="background-color:rgb(0,218,255)"'              
            WHEN min(h.temp) >= 12.2 and min(h.temp) <= 13.1 THEN 'data-style="background-color:rgb(0,244,255)"'               
            WHEN min(h.temp) >= 13.1 and min(h.temp) <= 14.0 THEN 'data-style="background-color:rgb(0,255,237)"'                  
            WHEN min(h.temp) >= 14.0 and min(h.temp) <= 15.2 THEN 'data-style="background-color:rgb(0,255,206)"'               
            WHEN min(h.temp) >= 15.2 and min(h.temp) <= 16.1 THEN 'data-style="background-color:rgb(0,255,167)"'               
            WHEN min(h.temp) >= 16.1 and min(h.temp) <= 17.0 THEN 'data-style="background-color:rgb(0,255,135)"'                 
            WHEN min(h.temp) >= 17.0 and min(h.temp) <= 18.2 THEN 'data-style="background-color:rgb(0,255,102)"'         
            WHEN min(h.temp) >= 18.2 and min(h.temp) <= 19.1 THEN 'data-style="background-color:rgb(0,255,64)"'               
            WHEN min(h.temp) >= 19.1 and min(h.temp) <= 20 THEN 'data-style="background-color:rgb(0,255,32)"'            
            WHEN min(h.temp) >= 20 and min(h.temp) <= 21.2 THEN 'data-style="background-color:rgb(0,255,0)"'              
            WHEN min(h.temp) >= 21.2 and min(h.temp) <= 22.1 THEN 'data-style="background-color:rgb(39,255,0)"'             
            WHEN min(h.temp) >= 22.1 and min(h.temp) <= 23 THEN 'data-style="background-color:rgb(71,255,0)"'                
            WHEN min(h.temp) >= 23 and min(h.temp) <= 24.2 THEN 'data-style="background-color:rgb(102,255,0)"'                
            WHEN min(h.temp) >= 24.2 and min(h.temp) <= 25.1 THEN 'data-style="background-color:rgb(142,255,0)"'               
            WHEN min(h.temp) >= 25.1 and min(h.temp) <= 26 THEN 'data-style="background-color:rgb(174,255,0)"'             
            WHEN min(h.temp) >= 26 and min(h.temp) <= 27.2 THEN 'data-style="background-color:rgb(206,255,0)"'               
            WHEN min(h.temp) >= 27.2 and min(h.temp) <= 28.1 THEN 'data-style="background-color:rgb(244,255,0)"'              
            WHEN min(h.temp) >= 28.1 and min(h.temp) <= 29 THEN 'data-style="background-color:rgb(255,237,0)"'            
            WHEN min(h.temp) >= 29 and min(h.temp) <= 30.2 THEN 'data-style="background-color:rgb(255,206,0)"'  
            WHEN min(h.temp) >= 30.2 and min(h.temp) <= 31.1 THEN 'data-style="background-color:rgb(255,167,0)"'               
            WHEN min(h.temp) >= 31.1 and min(h.temp) <= 32 THEN 'data-style="background-color:rgb(255,135,0)"'                
            WHEN min(h.temp) >= 32 and min(h.temp) <= 33.2 THEN 'data-style="background-color:rgb(255,102,0)"'               
            WHEN min(h.temp) >= 33.2 and min(h.temp) <= 34.1 THEN 'data-style="background-color:rgb(255,64,0)"' 
            WHEN min(h.temp) >= 34.1 and min(h.temp) <= 35 THEN 'data-style="background-color:rgb(255,32,0)"'            
            WHEN min(h.temp) >= 35  THEN 'data-style="background-color:rgb(255,0,0)"'                 
            ELSE NULL
               END css_style_min
from HANGINGTHREAD_SILO a
left join IOT_DEVICES b on b.ID = a.DEVICES_ID and b.ORGANIZATION = a.ORGANIZATIONS
left join SILO_SENSOR v on v.DEVICES_ID = b.outguid and v.ORGANIZATIONS = b.ORGANIZATION 
left join TEMPR_SILO h on h.name = v.NAME and h.ORGANIZATIONS = v.ORGANIZATIONS 
left join SILO z on z.id = a.ID_SILO
where TRIM(z.name) = TRIM('1201') and z.ORGANIZATION = 181
   
group by 
  z.name , 
  v.NAME_LVL
        
 ORDER BY      v.NAME_LVL desc

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Comment: You could apply a variation of this https://askmax.blog/2018/05/18/lazy-loading-report/ driven by tab selections https://explorer.co.uk/dynamic-selection-tabs-region-display-selectors-apex/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For posterity... I met with the user online to get a better idea of the problem they were trying to solve. Each of the 150+ regions on the page was using the same query with a different set of values in the where clause. While visually attractive, the performance hit of running so many queries on the same page - and the fact that each region had to be maintained individually - was too much.

I suggested using a single Interactive Report with Control Breaks on the field that was previously used to group individual regions. This solution performed perfectly and had the benefit of leveraging all of the other features of Interactive Reports, such as filtering (instead of using tabs to show groups of regions), charts, and more.

Answer (score 0):

I think you really need to ask yourself....why are you loading 150 regions on the same page.  What is the business need for this?  Why would a user need to see all 150 regions on the same page at the same time?

If I were you, I would break up the page.  This is information overload for the end user (and, seemingly cluttered).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, (I just don't have much experience with apex oracle, only 7 months) do you mean split into different pages ?? I decided so because this information is the same, I wanted it in one page but in a different tab! But only to download tabs if I tear it off. But as I understand it at this time there is no such possibility.

Comment: What do you mean by "I decided so because this information is the same, I wanted it in one page but in a different tab"? If the information is the same, why isn't one region enough? Why show it 150 times?

Comment: @DanMcGhan and I meant one type, that is, I have 150 different objects, and on these objects I output in 2 columns the maximum and minimum figures in each table separately. And I want these tables to be 20 in one tab

Comment: @DanMcGhan if I print 20 objects on the page, everything works fast, but if anything, everything slows down, I decided to split it into tabs,

Comment: I can not understand what you're talking about. Don't use the generic term "objects". Do you have 150 regions or 150 items on the page? What types of regions or items are they?

Comment: @DanMcGhan I have a page, it has 150 different regions, the treasury of these regions has its request with its ID, that is, I have 150 different requests on one page, each in my own region, I have placed these regions in tabs of up to 20 pieces !

Comment: What do you mean by the words "treasury" and "pieces"? We don't use these terms.

Comment: @DanMcGhan Sorry for my English, I understand that you want to help me, but with my level of English you are difficult.)) I have a page, it has 150 different regions, each of these regions has its own request with its ID, ie I have 150 different queries on one page, each in its own region, I pasted these regions in tabs (20 in the regions in the tab)!

Comment: No worries with respect to your English. You should hear my Spanish! :) However, when you're asking questions about a technical topic, you should use the terms used in the specific technology (APEX in this case). Okay, so you have 1 page. The page has 150 regions. You are placing the regions in groups of up to 20 under different tabs. I think we are clear up to that point now. Here are the next two questions I need you to answer: 1) What types of regions are they? Classic Reports, Interactive Reports, other? 2) Can you update your question with an example query from two different regions?

Comment: @DanMcGhan You understand that we asked ours)))) I'll update now!

Comment: Interesting, that doesn't look like a light-weight query :) Have a look at this post: https://rimblas.com/blog/2020/05/plugin-defer-report-load-on-tab-focus/ If that doesn't help, you may need to change your app around some so that it works more efficiently. I'm not sure Stack Overflow will help much more. If you'd like to meet online so that I can see the app and offer suggestions, please DM me on Twitter (https://twitter.com/dmcghan) or contact me via my blog (https://jsao.io/contact/). If you do reach out, please include the URL to this Stack Overflow question.